# How to use XML input for Update / Set statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-update

When I need to update a table through a stored procedure I use something like the following for this which usually works for me (using SQL Server 2012):

```
UPDATE  LogTable
SET     title = @title,
        summary = @summary,
        post = @post,
        departmentID = @departmentID
WHERE   postID = @postID
```

However, now I have the situation that my input is not from single parameters but is instead part of an XML input (defined as `@xmlMain xml`) while postID is a separate parameter (defined as `@postID int`).

I was trying to use something like the following here but then don't know how to apply a FROM statement here (which would be something like `FROM   @xmlMain.nodes('/root') AS [Xml_Tab]([Cols])` ):

```
UPDATE  LogTable
SET     title = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(title)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
        summary = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(summary)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        post = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(post)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        departmentID = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(departmentID)[1]', 'int')
WHERE   postID = @postID
```

How can I write this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET    title = b.title,
       summary = b.summary,
       post = b.post,
       departmentID = b.departmentID
FROM   LogTable A
       JOIN (SELECT title=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(title)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
                    summary=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(summary)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
                    post=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(post)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                    departmentID=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(departmentID)[1]', 'int'),
                    PostID=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(postID)[1]', 'int')
             FROM   @xmlMain.nodes('/root') AS [Xml_Tab]([Cols]) ) B
         ON a.postID = b.postID
```

Comment: Perfect, that works ! Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Comment: @user2571510 This answer and question is almost identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668766/sql-server-how-to-properly-use-xml-parameter-for-update-procedure

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Thanks and sorry - I looked at the other question and answer but wasn't sure I got this right here. Apologies for that !

Answer (score 1):

Try following query and check whether it is working or not:

```
UPDATE 
    LogTable
SET 
    title = Temp.Cols.value('@title','nvarchar(100)'),
    summary = Temp.Cols.value('@summary', 'nvarchar(500)'),
    post = Temp.Cols.value('@post', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    departmentID = Temp.Cols.value('@departmentID', 'int')
FROM 
    @xmlMain.nodes('/root/[YourXMLElementName]') AS Temp(Cols)
WHERE 
    postID = Temp.Cols.value('@postID', 'INT')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no performance issues you can use your initial code to update your log but simply fill your variables from new source like you wrote in your question:

```
SELECT  @title = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(title)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
        @summary = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(summary)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        @posT = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(post)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        @departmentID = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(departmentID)[1]', 'int')
FROM    @xmlMain.nodes('/root') AS [Xml_Tab]([Cols])

-- Your original code
UPDATE  LogTable
SET     title = @title,
        summary = @summary,
        post = @post,
        departmentID = @departmentID
WHERE   postID = @postID
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well - performance wise I would prefer one of the other options here but this is good to know, too.